# Permissions To Create New Item in CosmoDB in Data Explorer

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Question: What permissions is needed for an Azure Active Directory user to update/create records in Azure CosmoDB with the [Azure Cosmos DB Explorer](https://cosmos.azure.com/) or Data Explorer?

**UserA** has the Azure RBAC **Reader** role assigned to the **SubA** subscription where **mycosmodb** also resides.

I have the RBAC Contributor role, so on the Azure portal in data explorer I can create a new item

[image]

Here’s what we tried for userA and failed

Looked through [Built-in (RBAC) roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/role-based-access-control#built-in-roles) for cosmoDB and assigned the **DocumentDB Account Contributor role**.

[image]

Looked at the [Built-in role definitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-setup-rbac#built-in-role-definitions), and assigned **Cosmos DB Built-in Data Contributor**

[image]

Here’s the powershell to assign userA with the role **Cosmos DB Built-in Data Contributor**

```
$resourceGroupName = "myRg"
$accountName = "mycosmodb"
$roleDefinitionId = "/subscriptions/123ABC/resourceGroups/myRg/providers/Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/mycosmodb/sqlRoleDefinitions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002"
$principalId = "myprincipal123abc"
New-AzCosmosDBSqlRoleAssignment -AccountName $accountName `
    -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
    -RoleDefinitionId $roleDefinitionId `
    -Scope "/" `
    -PrincipalId $principalId
```

Verified that userA has been assigned with the role **Cosmos DB Built-in Data Contributor**

```
Get-AzCosmosDBSqlRoleAssignment `
-ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
-AccountName $accountName
```

**UserA** login to the [Azure Cosmos DB Explorer](https://cosmos.azure.com/) and we see this, but userA is not able to select a Subscription (even through userA as Reader (RBAC role) assigned).

[image]

Any help / idea is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You might need to assign [reader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#reader) role on that user at subscription level to provide the access.